# Why a user with ROLE_ADMIN has ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN automatically in friendsofsymfony bundle?

Tags: php, symfony

In my controller I run

```
$user = $this->get('security.token_storage')->getToken()->getUser();
dump($user);
```

This is my result:

[image: This is a result]

Comment: What is the value of the column roles of your user in your database ? Please give us your role_hierarchy in the `app/config/security.yml`

Comment: role_hierarchy:  
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_ADMIN]  
        ROLE_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER]

Comment: I find fos_user table column roles save ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN

Comment: For me all it's normal, what is your problem ?